# request.user.is_authenticated cycling between True and False when logged in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

I made a middleware that returns 403 Forbidden if the user is not authenticated but after logging in, each time I refresh the page I am logged in then logged out and so on.

This is only happening in production on Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet running Gunicorn and Nginx.

middleware.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def IsAuthMiddleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request):
        if (request.path.startswith('/dashboard') or 'account' in request.path) and not request.user.is_authenticated():
            context = {
                "title": "Not logged in",
                "message": "- You are not logged in."
            }
            return render(request, '403.html', context)

        response = get_response(request)

        if response.status_code == 403:
            res = render(request, '403.html', {'message': response.content.decode()})
            res.status_code = 403
            return res
        if response.status_code == 404:
            res = render(request, '404.html', {'message': response.content.decode()})
            res.status_code = 404
            return res

        return response

    return middleware
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Message
from dashboard.models import Subscriber, Newsletter, Unsubscription
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, ValidationError
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.core.validators import validate_email 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    context = {
        "title": "Home",
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)

def privacy(request):
    return render(request, 'main/privacy.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        context = {
            "title": "Contact",
            "msg": True,
            "good": True,
            "msg_content": "Your message has been sent and we will get back to you asap."
        }
        for _, item in request.POST.items():
            if item == '':
                context['good'] = False
                context['msg_content'] = "Please fill in every input"
                return render(request, 'main/contact.html', context)
        
        msg = Message(
            title   = request.POST['title'],
            email   = request.POST['email'],
            content = request.POST['content']
        )
        msg.save()

        return render(request, 'main/contact.html', context)

    else:
        context = {
            'title': 'Contact',
        }
        return render(request, 'main/contact.html', context)

def sub(request, id):
    try:
        newsletter = Newsletter.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('- requested newsletter does not exist')
    context = {
        'title': f'Subscribe to {newsletter.name}',
        'msg': False,
        'newsletter': newsletter
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['subemail']
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            context['msg'] = True
            context['msg_content'] = 'Email is not valid'
            return render(request, 'main/sub.html', context)
        sub = Subscriber(first_name=fname, last_name=lname, email=email, subscription=newsletter)
        try:
            sub.save(confirm=True)
        except IntegrityError:
            context['msg'] = True
            context['msg_content'] = 'Email is already subscribed'
            return render(request, 'main/sub.html', context)
        context['title'] = context['title'].replace('Subscribe', 'Subscribed')
        context['subscriber'] = sub
        return render(request, 'main/subbed.html', context)
    return render(request, 'main/sub.html', context)
        
def unsub(request, id):
    try:
        n = Newsletter.objects.get(id=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('- newsletter does not exist')
    context = {
        'title': f'Unsubscribe from {n.name}',
        'msg': False,
        'newsletter': n
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['unsubemail']
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            context['msg'] = True
            context['msg_content'] = 'Email is not valid'
            return render(request, 'main/unsub.html', context)
        try:
            sub = Subscriber.objects.get(email=email, subscription=n)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            context['msg'] = True
            context['msg_content'] = 'Email is not subscribed'
            return render(request, 'main/unsub.html', context)
        if not sub.is_recv:
            context['msg'] = True
            context['msg_content'] = 'Email is not subscribed'
            return render(request, 'main/unsub.html', context)
        unsub = Unsubscription(subscription=n, prev=sub)
        unsub.save()
        sub.delete()
        context['unsub'] = unsub
        return render(request, 'main/unsubbed.html', context)
    return render(request, 'main/unsub.html', context)

@csrf_exempt
def signupconfirm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sub = Subscriber.objects.get(id=int(request.POST['id']))
        sub.is_recv = True
        sub.consent_date = timezone.now()
        sub.save()
        context = {
            'title': f'Successfully signed up to {sub.subscription.name}',
            'subscriber': sub,
            'validated': True
        }
        return render(request, 'main/subbed.html', context)
    return HttpResponseNotFound('no origin')
```

I tried to use different session engines but none of that worked and is_authenticated keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the url for log out hidden on the page?

Button with this href instead of {% url 'logout' %}

```
href="javascript:{document.getElementById('logout').submit()}"
```

Then have this form somewhere on the page.

```
<form id="logout" method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" />
</form>
```

It may be sorted now with a newer version of django but I remember having to do this on my homepage because of something similar.

You can also use login_required from djangos own decorators. I've not done much with middleware before but hope that helps you.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 

@login_required
def your_view_name(request):
    ....
```

Comment: thanks I'll use the decorator from now on but the session is still not working properly and the data is still disappearing every reload and then reappearing in the next one.